# How do I add in a octagon shape from a plane mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image: This is what I'm trying to get. The guy in the video gets this by just creating a plane, but when I do it, my plane looks like a complete circle.]I'm new to Blender and currently watching tutorials on modeling. In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KPWNn2PhXYs), at 6:50, the person adds a *Plane* mesh that is already in a octagon form; it has 4 vertices but looks like an octagon. I've been trying to find out how he did this but can't find out the answer.

Comment: Could you be more specific. I see two planes, but not an octagon. You can add up to 2 screenshots to further explain your problem.

Comment: The guy does add in 2 planes but they look like octagons as seen by 6:57. When I try to add in a plane in my project, they look like complete circles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The guy does not have *Screencast Keys* enabled, but if he did, you would know that he keyed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> (<kbd>1</kbd>, not <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>), which is the keyboard shortcut for adding a *Subdivision surface* modifier immediately after adding the plane.

If <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> doesn't work for you, you can go to the *Properties panel > Object modifiers tab* and add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier manually. Even if you use the shortcut, you still need to tweak the settings in that tab. A normal *Subdivision Surface* modifier looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

To have an octagon out of a square (4 vertices) add a subsurf modifier

[image]

To make a real octagon add a mesh>Circle and make it 8 vertices:

[image]